# RPZ in Bind DNS server not working

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system, bind

I have an external Bind DNS server which is used by a number of remote machines (limited by IP only). The current setup of this server is to act as a forwarding server. I am trying to block certain domains by forwarding them to a request form page which sits on another external web server. I have created a RPZ but I am having trouble getting it to actually work as intended.

```
$TTL 60
@            IN    SOA  localhost. root.localhost.  (
                          2015112501   ; serial
                          1h           ; refresh
                          30m          ; retry
                          1w           ; expiry
                          30m)         ; minimum
                   IN     NS    localhost.

localhost       A   127.0.0.1

www.bad-site.com    A        IP ADDRESS OF SERVER HOSTING REQUEST FORM PAGE

www.bad-site.com   CNAME    request-form-site.com.
```

If I just change the A record to point to the IP address of the web server where the request form page is hosted then it does nothing - the user can still visit the bad domain.

If I change the CNAME to the domain of the request form page then I get a certificate error because the browser thinks something dodgy is going on (I completely get this which is fine). I cannot install certificates on every machine so this method will not work for me. However why is the A record method not working?

Comment: The name/IP mapping you are trying to add in an RPZ is **NOT** how an RPZ works, doing what you do is just normal DNS mapping, overriding real nameservers, and you can do that by being a fake authoritative on that specific name/its zone. You don't need bind to do that and I would recommend not too as not very simple, `dnsmasq` and `unbound` might be better choices for you. See https://www.isc.org/rpz/ for a filtering on name you need a CNAME.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - As Bind is already implemented as a forwarding DNS server, would it be possible to achieve what I want to do with Bind - or is there another application I can use alongside Bind?